# alignment is not proper when i add div dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi am implementing add more functionality on my web page when dynamically adding form fields going fine but it is not added row-wise properly form fields going here there how to do alignment of form fields row-wise here and I have move + button right end, do any suggestion if I am wrong anywhere  in the code

```js
 $('#clone_button').click(function() {
  $('#clone_wrapper')
  .clone()
  .append('clone')
  .appendTo($('#clone_wrapper'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/css/preload.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/css/plugins.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/css/style.light-blue-500.min.css">
     <script src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
 <div id="ms-preload" class="ms-preload">
      <div id="status">
        <div class="spinner">
          <div class="dot1"></div>
          <div class="dot2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-full-page bg-primary back-fixed">
      <div class="md-500 absolute-center">
   
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
    <<h1 class="color-primary text-big">Let's Add User</h1>
             <div class="col-md-2">
     <div class="row ">
        <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-block " id="clone_button">
                      + <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i></button> 
      </div>
      </div>
            <form>
              <fieldset>
     <div id="clone_wrapper">
     <div class="col-md-3 form-line">
               
       <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="select111" class="col-md-2 control-label">Role</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                          <select id="select111" class="form-control selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false">
                            <option>Ea nam qui vel consequatur</option>
                            <option>Dolorem perspiciatis adipisci </option>
                            <option>Aperiam, debitis deleniti</option>
                            <option>Accusamus non qui amet eum</option>
                            <option>Doloremque commodi impedit</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
     </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
                 <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <div class="input-group">
                   
                    <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-user">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="ms-form-user" class="form-control"> </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <div class="input-group">
                   
                    <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-pass">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="password" id="ms-form-pass" class="form-control"> </div>
                </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <div class="input-group">
                   
                    <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-pass">Email</label>
                    <input type="password" id="ms-form-pass" class="form-control"> </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
    
       <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="select111" class="col-md-2 control-label">Profile</label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                          <select id="select111" class="form-control selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false">
                            <option>Ea nam qui vel consequatur</option>
                            <option>Dolorem perspiciatis adipisci </option>
                            <option>Aperiam, debitis deleniti</option>
                            <option>Accusamus non qui amet eum</option>
                            <option>Doloremque commodi impedit</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
               </div> 
</div>       

    
    <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="row ">
                   <div class="col-md-5 form-line">
       <button class="btn  btn-raised btn-block">back</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5 form-line">
                    <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-block">Done</button>
                  </div>
                </div> 
</div>
   
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  
      </div>
```

```
<div id="ms-preload" class="ms-preload">
      <div id="status">
        <div class="spinner">
          <div class="dot1"></div>
          <div class="dot2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-full-page bg-primary back-fixed">
      <div class="md-500 absolute-center">

       <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-block">
          <<h1 class="color-primary text-big">Let's Add User</h1>
             <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="row ">
                          <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-block " id="clone_button">
                      + <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i></button> 
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     <form>
              <fieldset>
              <div id="clone_wrapper">
              <div class="col-md-3 form-line">

                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="select111" class="col-md-2 control-label">Role</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                          <select id="select111" class="form-control selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false">
                            <option>Ea nam qui vel consequatur</option>
                            <option>Dolorem perspiciatis adipisci </option>
                            <option>Aperiam, debitis deleniti</option>
                            <option>Accusamus non qui amet eum</option>
                            <option>Doloremque commodi impedit</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                 </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
                 <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <div class="input-group">

                    <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-user">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="ms-form-user" class="form-control"> </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <div class="input-group">

                    <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-pass">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="password" id="ms-form-pass" class="form-control"> </div>
                </div>
                 </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <div class="input-group">

                    <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-pass">Email</label>
                    <input type="password" id="ms-form-pass" class="form-control"> </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 form-line">

                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="select111" class="col-md-2 control-label">Profile</label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                          <select id="select111" class="form-control selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false">
                            <option>Ea nam qui vel consequatur</option>
                            <option>Dolorem perspiciatis adipisci </option>
                            <option>Aperiam, debitis deleniti</option>
                            <option>Accusamus non qui amet eum</option>
                            <option>Doloremque commodi impedit</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
               </div>   
</div>                 


          <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="row ">
                   <div class="col-md-5 form-line">
                   <button class="btn  btn-raised btn-block">back</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5 form-line">
                    <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-block">Done</button>
                  </div>
                </div>  
</div>

              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: try `$('#clone_button').on("click",function() {  ...... }` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add new form on every button click, but you are cloning entire newly formed element (`form`).

See the updated code where every newly created `form-group` added to `fieldset`. And applied class `row` for every new `form-group` so that it's available in new line.

```js
var clones = 1;
$('#clone_button').click(function() {
  $('#clone_wrapper')
    .clone()
    .append('clone').attr('id', '#clone_wrapper' + clones++)
    .appendTo($('.form-set'));
});
```

```css
.form-set #clone_wrapper{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/css/preload.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/css/plugins.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/css/style.light-blue-500.min.css">
<script src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/testbucket092601/material-style-1.5.2/HTML/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
<div id="ms-preload" class="ms-preload">
  <div id="status">
    <div class="spinner">
      <div class="dot1"></div>
      <div class="dot2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bg-full-page bg-primary back-fixed">
  <div class="md-500 absolute-center">

    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <<h1 class="color-primary text-big">Let's Add User</h1>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="row ">
                <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-block " id="clone_button">
                      + <i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <form>
              <fieldset class="form-set">
                <div id="clone_wrapper" class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3 form-line">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="select111" class="col-md-2 control-label">Role</label>
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select id="select111" class="form-control selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false">
                            <option>Ea nam qui vel consequatur</option>
                            <option>Dolorem perspiciatis adipisci </option>
                            <option>Aperiam, debitis deleniti</option>
                            <option>Accusamus non qui amet eum</option>
                            <option>Doloremque commodi impedit</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                      <div class="input-group">

                        <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-user">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="ms-form-user" class="form-control"> </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                      <div class="input-group">

                        <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-pass">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="password" id="ms-form-pass" class="form-control"> </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2 form-line">
                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                      <div class="input-group">

                        <label class="control-label" for="ms-form-pass">Email</label>
                        <input type="password" id="ms-form-pass" class="form-control"> </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-2 form-line">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="select111" class="col-md-2 control-label">Profile</label>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <select id="select111" class="form-control selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false">
                            <option>Ea nam qui vel consequatur</option>
                            <option>Dolorem perspiciatis adipisci </option>
                            <option>Aperiam, debitis deleniti</option>
                            <option>Accusamus non qui amet eum</option>
                            <option>Doloremque commodi impedit</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
              <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 form-line">
                      <button class="btn  btn-raised btn-block">back</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 form-line">
                      <button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-block">Done</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```